# Is there a way to add a new line after every ']' in Python?

Tags: python

I originally had a string containing BBCode in which I wanted to format it better so it can be readable.

I had something like

```
['"9-5[centre][notice][url=https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/playlist?list=PL3OTylWB5pG7s7JowIUEYBiPkKR0GRRRG][b]\\u25ba osu! Mapping Theory[\\/b][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/0uGeZzyobSY]Linear Momentum[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/zOzi8Q655vs]Linear Momentum 2[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/Rm5l0UDJLcQ]Angular Momentum and Circular Flow[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/hRc3Xm0wI7s]Active and Passive Mapping[\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/OgNhsZpKRYc]Slider Flow[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/e05hOKXfWOk]Stream Flow[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/zYAujNMPVbY]Slider Mechanics[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/ZOtkAQ3MoNE]Aesthetics by Symmetry[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/WnLG31LaQx0]Aesthetics by Complexity[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/i323hh7-CAQ]Defining Flow[\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/hNnF5NLoOwU]Flow and Aesthetics[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/tq8fu_-__8M]Angle Emphasis[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/6ilBsa_dV8k]Strain[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/KKDnLsIyRp0]Pressure[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/jm43HilQhYk]Tension[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/-_Mh0NbpHXo]Song Choice[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/BNjVu8xq4os]Song Length[\\/url]\\n\\n[url=https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/playlist?list=PL3OTylWB5pG6t5MCwGnq87iYZnE5G7aZL][b]\\u25ba osu! Rambling[\\/b][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/-Beeh7dKyTk]Storyboards[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/i6zzHMzwIzU]Why[\\/url]\\n\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/_sBP7ttRQog]0 BPM[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/UgtR6WnuTT8]ppv2 Pt.1[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/Bx14u5tltyE]ppv2 Pt.2[\\/url] | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/-095yuSLE4Y]Super high star rating[\\/url][\\/notice][url=https:\\/\\/amo.s-ul.eu\\/oApvJHWA][b]Skin v3.4[\\/b][\\/url]\\n[size=85]Personal edit of [url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/forum\\/t\\/481314]Re:m skin by Choilicious[\\/url][\\/size]\\n\\n[img]http:\\/\\/puu.sh\\/qqv6C\\/0aaca52f51.jpg[\\/img][url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/u\\/Satellite][img]http:\\/\\/puu.sh\\/qqv6K\\/94681bed3f.jpg[\\/img][\\/url][url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/u\\/Sellenite][img]http:\\/\\/puu.sh\\/qqv6T\\/c943ed1703.jpg[\\/img][\\/url][url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/u\\/Morinaga][img]http:\\/\\/puu.sh\\/qqv70\\/cfbdb2a242.jpg[\\/img][\\/url][url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/u\\/-Mo-][img]http:\\/\\/puu.sh\\/qqv77\\/ca489f2d00.jpg[\\/img][\\/url]\\n[notice]I don\'t really do nomination stuff often anymore. \\nHowever, please do show me your map if it\'s any of the following:[box=][b]Bounty[\\/b]\\n[size=50]High priority modding for these artists\\/songs (maybe a GD, just ask).\\nPreferably non-cut versions and songs that have no ranked maps yet.[\\/size]\\n\\nYuuhei Satellite\\nYuuhei Catharsis\\nShoujo Fractal\\nHoneyWorks (non-vocaloid)\\nTrySail\\nClariS\\n\\nClariS - CLICK (Asterisk DnB Remix), [size=85]either version.[\\/size]\\nfhana - Outside of Melancholy, [size=85]a version that isn\'t cut pls[\\/size]\\nAny cover of \\u7832\\u96f7\\u6483\\u6226\\u3001\\u59cb\\u3081![\\/box]I also do storyboard checks for any map.\\n\\nPMs are open for anything. Ask me anything. \\nAsk me what my favourite colour is if you really want even.[\\/notice][box=Guests][b]Ranked[\\/b]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/1575100][img]http:\\/\\/s.ppy.sh\\/images\\/insane.png[\\/img] senya - Terasareru kurai no Shiawase [Lunatic][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/1794557][img]http:\\/\\/s.ppy.sh\\/images\\/insane.png[\\/img] senya - Arehateta Chijou no Uta [Collab Insane][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/1592915][img]http:\\/\\/s.ppy.sh\\/images\\/insane.png[\\/img] Tanaka Hirokazu - C-TYPE [TetriS-TYPE] [S-TYPE][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/1490130][img]http:\\/\\/s.ppy.sh\\/images\\/insane.png[\\/img] TrySail - adrenaline!!! [Insane][\\/url] [size=85]Slightly ruined version.[\\/size]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/1401096][img]http:\\/\\/s.ppy.sh\\/images\\/insane.png[\\/img] senya - Shunkan Everlasting [Insane][\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/osu.ppy.sh\\/b\\/795269][img]
```

Basically unreadable currently.

I tried making it look like

```
['"9-5[centre][notice][url=https:\\/\\/www.youtube.com\\/playlist?list=PL3OTylWB5pG7s7JowIUEYBiPkKR0GRRRG]
[b]
\\u25ba osu! Mapping Theory[\\/b]
[\\/url]\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/0uGeZzyobSY]
Linear Momentum[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/zOzi8Q655vs]
Linear Momentum 2[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/Rm5l0UDJLcQ]
Angular Momentum and Circular Flow[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/hRc3Xm0wI7s]
Active and Passive Mapping[\\/url]
\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/OgNhsZpKRYc]
Slider Flow[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/e05hOKXfWOk]
Stream Flow[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/zYAujNMPVbY]
Slider Mechanics[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/ZOtkAQ3MoNE]
Aesthetics by Symmetry[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/WnLG31LaQx0]
Aesthetics by Complexity[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/i323hh7-CAQ]
Defining Flow[\\/url]
\\n[url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/hNnF5NLoOwU]
Flow and Aesthetics[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/tq8fu_-__8M]
Angle Emphasis[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/6ilBsa_dV8k]
Strain[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/KKDnLsIyRp0]
Pressure[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/jm43HilQhYk]
Tension[\\/url]
 | [url=https:\\/\\/youtu.be\\/-_Mh0NbpHXo]
Song Choice[\\/url]
 |
```

Where there's a new line after every ']'

I've tried tweaking `re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", str(x))` to fit what I need but it just deletes everything inside of them. (I have no idea how regex works)

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a regular expression, just use the simple `str.replace()` function.

```
x = x.replace(']', ']\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on exactly what you want your output to look like.

I interpreted your output as wanting a newline after each `url=` tag, which would require the following regex:

```
output = re.sub(r"(\[url.*?\])", r"\1\n", input)
```

The brackets `()` form a capture group which is then used in the replace statement as `\1` since its the first  unnamed capture group.

You can change the regex to your will but just keep the stuff you want to keep within the capture group.

If you want to experiment with regex you can use https://regexr.com/ which is an amazing resource when fiddling around with regex.